# error trying to build a histogram using r with the rStudio application

Tags: r, rstudio

Using ggplot2 I am attempting to create a histogram.  I have a column that is full on the continents.  I need to add all the continents which I attempted to do with the aggregate function.

```
data <- aggregate(country$continent,country["continent"], sum)
hist(data)
```

Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. You currently group by continent and sum continent names for each country. You cannot do "USA" + "Russia" = "Love"

Comment: Ok I have a data_frame called country which has a column called continent.  I wish to groupby and count the continent column.  So, for example USA = 5, Russia = 2, etc.   After that is done, I am going to make a histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code :

```
data.frame(table(country$continent))
```

will create a dataframe where one column is the continent and the other is the number of countries in the continent.

Comment: working on histogram `hist(data$Freq)`

Comment: not looking as expected.

Comment: `barplot(table(country$continent))`

Comment: Closing in on this problem, thanks,  it did look 100% better.

Comment: Working on changing the frequency to a percentage. Researching this I find the following code `data[, percen := sum(freq), by=list(name,cat1)]`
`data[, percen := freq/percen]` working to see if it is a fit.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work`data1 <- data.frame(data$Freq(sum)/data$Freq)`

Comment: `data['percen'] <- data$Freq/sum(data$Freq)` I would recommend you to go through some video courses like udemy. You currently lack understanding how programming languages work. And you should start with python. It is easier to understand while R has too many ways to do the same thing which makes it harder to learn.

Comment: Thanks, I am taking courses right now at the local university.  We just started r, so this is a learning curve, I'm pushing through.

Comment: `data['percen'] <- data$Freq/sum(data$Freq) ` sorry this isn't working for me.  I'll keep working on it. thanks

Comment: I did not check it. What is the error?

Comment: `data1 <- data.frame(sum(data$Freq)/data$Freq)`
> `hist(data1)`
Error in hist.default(data1) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: `data['percen'] <- data$Freq/sum(data$Freq)`
`hist(data)`
Error in hist.default(data) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Histogram is not a barplot. data['percen'] creates another column in the same dataframe. Calling hist(data) means you want to create a frequency histogram from the data frame. And data frame is not one column but many. So what you want is probably `barplot(data$Freq/sum(data$Freq))` or `barplot(data$percen)`

Comment: really, I want a histogram

Comment: For categorical variables R function hist() does not work. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables  And hist() can only be applied to a numerical vector. Variable data is not a numerical vector it is a data.frame or a data.table.